# Why the original element got changed when I modify the copy created by .dup method? Ruby and REXML

Tags: ruby, rexml

I just tested the following steps in irb and got something odd:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rexml/document'  
include REXML

e1=Element.new("E1")
e2=Element.new("E2")
e1.add_element(e2)

e1Dup=e1.dup
puts e1
puts e1Dup

e1.delete_element(e1.elements[1])
puts e1
puts e1Dup
```

I only want changes on e1, however, the result shows both element got changed. How could this happen? The result is below:

```
<E1><E2/></E1>
<E1><E2/></E1>
<E1/>
<E1/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's `dup` function only makes a shallow duplicate of the object. Its internal data, such as that stored in attributes (which is what the `elements` method is accessing) does not get duplicated. So you have two totally distinct objects `e1` and `e1Dup`, but their *children* are the same. In C++, you would say that the two pointers are accessing the same memory location. To fully duplicate the tree of elements, you would have to recursively call `.dup` on each child node and replace them on the duplicated `e1Dup`.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I understand what you mean, however, as I can see to write an recursive procedure to do it is too complicated. Alternatively, I found another solution, just simply use `e2 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(e1))`, everything is fine. I don't if it's the best solution but it works now. Thanks all the same